# User with many types, how to SQL

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I'm in the database designing of a product that I'm creating, I need a little help in the right sql shemas that I should use. 
Let's say that I have a table of users, and each user can select many withdrawal methods, how do I create a relation between user table and withdrawmethods table to be able to insert in the right column in users (paytype for example) as many selected methods by user ?

E.G :

```
User id  Name    PayType
0        Anthony 01,03 
1        Merlin  02

PayID Title
01    Paypal
02    Bank
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't use PayType column. Many to many relations should be implemented as new table with foreign key to each connected table. E.g. table users_withdrawal: user_id (fk from users table), withdrawalmethod_id (fk from withdrawalmethods table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have another table that is a reference table between the two:

```
CREATE TABLE user_method (
    UserId int(10),
    PayID int(10)
)
```

Using this table, any user can have any number of PayIDs associated.

Comment: Yes I am always using that type of relations, but is there a way to make it directly table to table ?

Comment: @ChaibiAlaa Not very efficiently. If you store multiple values in a single column on a table, it is harder and less efficient to join on those values. If you aren't worried about joins, you could also just make that field a TEXT column and store a comma-delimited list of the ids per user. However, I still recommend the third table linking the 2 together.